# Prior Art Request: Asynchronous Live Streaming from a mobile phone, US9445150

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, video, streaming, us9445150

I came across a pair of granted patents that seem rather frivolous, and I'd appreciate some help digging up prior art around them. Priority date on both is April 19, 2013.

https://patents.google.com/patent/US9445150B2/en
https://patents.google.com/patent/US9178631B2/en

They cover Asynchronous live streaming media from a mobile phone; one focuses on video, the other on audio.

Here's a summary of the first independent claim (system) from the first patent:

> Periodically performs the following:
>
> 1. Receive and buffer a series of contiguous video files. After enough video files have been received:
>
>    > 1. Assign an index for the received video files
>    > 2. Transmit the received files & associated index to a remote server for broadcasting
> 2. Next, send a notification containing the index to an application on the broadcast server telling it the index & video files were sent, which causes the application to retrieve the video index & associated files

The second independent claim is a method claim that adds a requirement that the camera is the source for the video file.

The third independent claim covers the server-side application receiving messages from the above process.

As far as I can tell, the async part refers to uploading to the server using something similar to HTTP Live Streaming protocol, but it can also refer to a node.js server implementation. Not 100% sure. Would appreciate some input from the community on this one. Thanks!

Edit:
I tried to summarize the first claim, but here's the full text as requested:

> 1. A system, comprising:
>
> a handheld computing device that is configured to perform the following on a periodic basis when in an asynchronous streaming mode for a streaming video session:
>
> receive and buffer video data, wherein the buffered video data includes a plurality of contiguous video samples;
>
> after a predefined amount of contiguous video samples have been buffered, perform the following:
>
> > assign an index for the predefined amount of contiguous video samples, and
> >
> > asynchronously transmit that predefined amount of contiguous video samples and the assigned index for that predefined amount of contiguous video samples to a storage subsystem of a broadcast server system, wherein the storage subsystem is located remotely from the handheld computing device; and
>
> upon a determination that the predefined amount of contiguous video samples and the corresponding assigned index have been received by the storage subsystem, transmit a notification message to an application server of the broadcast server system that includes the assigned index and indicates that the predefined amount of contiguous video samples is stored on the storage subsystem of the broadcast server, wherein the notification message is configured to cause the application server to fetch the predefined amount of contiguous video samples according to the index included in the notification message and process those video samples for broadcasting to a plurality of client computing devices.

Potential Prior Art. Please comment if you think any of these SO QAs sufficiently address these patents.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444791/streaming-video-from-an-iphone
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849591/how-can-i-convert-iphone-captured-video-to-http-live-streaming-files
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719538/realtime-audio-video-streaming-from-iphone-to-another-device-browser-or-iphone
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960782/upload-live-streaming-video-from-iphone-like-ustream-or-qik

Comment: That isn’t the whole first claim. To infringe on a claim you need to implement every aspect of it. Please quote the whole claim.

Comment: Full text of the first claim added per your request.

Comment: I don't see any of those posts explicitly talking about an index. Also the phone waits until acknowledgment from  the storage system of received,   indexed material, and then  the phone tells an application server to broadcast it.

Comment: Both HLS (2009) and RTMP (2012) streaming video protocol specifications are built around using indexes. Neither refers to it as an index, but any video encoding engineer would agree with that assessment. Does that address your concern, @GeorgeWhite?

Comment: [Link to Initial RTMP Specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf)

Comment: [Link to initial HLS Specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-00)

Comment: [Link for summary of streaming media protocols](http://letzgro.net/blog/the-variety-of-streaming-protocols/) (with references to utilizing an "index")